# Update a text when cart is not empty

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a banner on my Wordpress website that I want to be updated when the cart is not empty by Ajax.

Here is the non Ajaxified version:

```
function dynamic_banner() {
    
    $atts = '<div class="woofc-shipping">' . alg_wc_get_left_to_free_shipping('<span style="color:#F79917"><i class="fas fa-shipping-fast" style="margin-left: 5px;"></i>Add %amount_left_for_free_shipping%  more for Free shipping</span> <div class="woofc-total-right"></div>') . '</div>';
    
    if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
    $(".ban-text").replaceWith('<?php echo $atts; ?>')});
    </script>
    <?php   
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'dynamic_banner');
```

This is the HTML

```
<div class="head_strip over--hide" style="display: block;">
<p><strong>Free fast delivery*</strong> in purchases over <span class="special-price">295 NIS</span> even during the closure period!</span></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: The html generated output is required in your question, or the original html related to `.ban-text` selector… To understand how to Ajaxify that to be refreshed on cart changes, see [those threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+Ajaxify)

Comment: Sorry, has been edited and added.

Comment: Nest time, please, try to translate your texts into english as StackOverFlow is an english web site. I don't see in your provide generated html, any tag with the selector `class="ban-text"`

Comment: Hey, friend, i was viewing your previous answers and i got a solution! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have found a solution thanks to  [those threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754%20Ajaxify) by [LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec)

Functions.php Code:

```
// Shortcode for the banner 
function display_free_shipping_progress() {
    return get_free_shipping_progress();
}
add_shortcode('fs_progress', 'display_free_shipping_progress');

// Function that makes calculations and display
function get_free_shipping_progress() {
    $atts = '<div class="woofc-shipping">' . alg_wc_get_left_to_free_shipping('<span style="color:#F79917"><i class="fas fa-shipping-fast" style="margin-left: 5px;"></i>הוסיפי עוד %amount_left_for_free_shipping% למשלוח חינם</span> <div class="woofc-total-right"></div>') . '</div>';

    $prodgress = WC()->cart->total;

    //Check if cart has something else show default
    if( $prodgress > 0 ) {
        return '<div class="head_strip over--hide" style="display: block;">' . $atts . '</div>';
    } else {
        return '<div class="head_strip over--hide" style="display: block;"><span class="ban-text"><strong>*משלוח מהיר חינם</strong > בקניה מעל<span class="special-price">295₪</span> גם בתקופת הסגר!</span></div>';
    }
}

// Refreshing "free shipping" progress on cart ajax events
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'refresh_free_shipping_progress' );
function refresh_free_shipping_progress( $fragments ){
    $fragments['.head_strip'] = get_free_shipping_progress();

    return $fragments;
}
```

Have passed all HTML needed to shortcode for simplicity like was recommended.